# @FindBy Annotations not allowed here for CSS

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

When trying to do this

```
VisibleForTesting        @FindBy(css="li:nthchild(2).NoBullet.jmsbullet>h3>a[href^='javascript:ShowSelectedAddInScreen']")

private WebElement HolidayLink;
```

I get the error

"Annotations are not allowed here"

Why does @VisibileforTesting not allow annotations?

Comment: what happens if u remove the private key word?

Comment: Strange when I add @VisibileForTesting after removing it, it doesn't seem to complain about annotations anymore. Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why u need private element here....it is not recommended to use private while u use @VisibileforTesting annotation.

u can find derails here

[Guava @VisibleForTesting : Help me with a complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051476/gauva-visiblefortesting-help-me-with-a-complete-example)

Comment: is this helped saqib?