# what is the advantage of using @VisibleForTesting?

Tags: java, annotations, guava

is @VisibleForTesting is just used before non-public methods to indicate developers that the scope of the method is made package-private just for testing purpose or is there any other advantage of using this annotation.

Comment: None it's a markup annotation, some kind of "for your information"

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24051476/gauva-visiblefortesting-help-me-with-a-complete-example

Comment: Well, you _can_ have static analysis that enforces it, if you like.